# How to save HTML5 time attribute input to My SQL

Tags: php, mysql, html, types, time

Hi I have a problem with HTML5 time attribute.

My code looks like this,

```
 <input type="time" name="e_time">
```

the sample output is looks like this

```
[e_time] => 19:08
```

It gives an array in 24 hours format. But the problem is My SQL is not accepting this in "time " data type. How do I do this? I tried adding

```
$time2 = $_POST["e_time"] . ":00";
```

and added :00 for the end of the string but it still fails. can anyone suggest me how to solve this? Thanks!

Comment: I assume you are submitting this form to a PHP script?

Comment: yes. I forgot to mention that.

Comment: Can you please show us some more code: how do you build and send the query? Also, please explicit what "fails" means: error message? wrong value inserted? I suspect you overlooked a TIME value must be enclosed in quotes, like a string.

Comment: and a `var_dump($_POST)` to see what is being sent to the post page. Did you try `(string)$_POST['e_time'].':00'`?

Comment: It would be very useful to know what the actual error message is that you get back from MySQL...  MySQL is quite forgiving when you save timestamps.

Comment: Thanks a  lot @Cumbo You made my day. It works now.  Thanks all who helped me :)